# Cmdlet getter and setters?

Tags: powershell

In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets there appear to be getter and setter scriptblocks. Where can I read more about how this is used? I thought those were for classes and/or C#.

```
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ParameterSetName = "Test01")]
public string UserName
{
  get { return userName; }
  set { userName = value; }
}
private string userName;
```

Comment: This _is_ C# code - meant to be used to create a - by definition compiled - _cmdlet_, as opposed to a written-in-PowerShell _advanced function / script_.

Comment: Thanks, @mklement0. Perhaps the page should mention something about "compiled" or "C#." I do not find either of those on the page.

Comment: I agree that it could be made clearer at least in the introductory page for that section, though note that the term _cmdlet_ is generally only used for compiled code. You can suggest amending the docs at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues.

Comment: My apologies, @mklement0. I thought the term "cmdlet" also applied to plain-text .ps1 scripts. I have more to learn.